# Grafana webhooks - failed to send

Tags: webhooks, grafana

I'm trying to set up Grafana to send webhooks to Microsoft Teams. I'm able to curl via terminal to the address but it's not possible via Grafanas interface.

I add the URL to Grafanas "webhook" and when I click "Test" it only shows me an error. Anyone know the solution?

I have not entered username/password since i don't know what to supply.

Comment: What does your grafana logs say? Im not sure microsoft teams will accept the webhooks from grafana.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this also.
With a variety of settings (post, put, slack, webhook)
Long story short, Grafana doesn't support the team webhook format.

I Can curl the webhook and get the hello world example to work (without credentials so it isn't the username and password).

**Error grafana gives is:**

```
 Webhook response status 400 Bad Request
```

[Getting started with connectors](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/GetStarted)

[Action reference](https://dev.outlook.com/actions/reference)